# Launching two animations with one div - how do I join both scripts and where do I put the action?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm in need of some help :s
I want two animations to launch when I hover a div (it's a button, the top part I want a fade in color, the bottom part a rolldown opacity). I checked a couple of questions here, and I understand how it's supposed to work, but I'm really new to jquery and I'm stuck in how to make two things work at once... and in where I should put the hover action.

These are the two scripts I want to convert to one:

ROLLDOWN:

```
$(function() {
    $('.hoverImg').css({"top" : "-170px"});
    $('.jwrap').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.hoverImg').stop()
            .animate({"top" : "0"}, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('.hoverImg').stop()
            .animate({"top" : "-170px"}, 300);
    });
});
```

FADE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="jwrap">
    <img src="image/Q1bigOff.png" alt="Image1"  />
    <img src="image/Q1bigOn2.png" alt="Image2" class="hoverImg" />
</div>

<div class="fadehover">
<img src="image/Q1Off.png" alt="" class="a" />
<img src="image/Q1On.png" alt="" class="b" />
</div>
```

now, I'm guessing I could make a big  on top of both effects and make my actions launch when I hover it? If you could help me wth that code... I would be terribly thankful.

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) example of your code? This sounds relatively simple but it's a little unclear what you want your animation to do.

Comment: Good idea. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/CVfLp/ although I pasted the second piece of code and it doesn't work (I don't know how to paste it correctly, sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe here is what you want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/CVfLp/3/

I moved the animations over to functions so we can trigger them whereever we want. Using the jquery find method I made sure I only animate the child elements of the parent div. You need to wrap `this` with a jquery select function to get access to the jquery function like so: `$(this)`.

Changed the background for the parent div to red for testing purposes.

Comment: GENEIOUS. It works perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I will study your solution, you saved me!

Comment: Can you make an updated jsfiddle? It's probably a small oversight.

Comment: (Edited) Now I have this working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/wBAf3/ BUT I need to make these clickable buttons (links). How can I do that? Any change in the html seems to break the functionality of the effect

Comment: Instead of the images you'll need to move your code to work with the added links instead... I don't quite have the time but start by wrapping the links arround the images and making them block level elements with `display: block;` and work from there.

Comment: Solved @sg3s ! I added the link in the class="a" image. Thanks again for all your help, jquery-guru ;)